# Reorder IE Context Menu

Tags: internet-explorer, contextmenu, bho, right-click

We have developed an Internet Explorer Addon using BHO and C#. We added a few context menu actions (for the IE that are using the addon) as well. 
We've used the registery entries under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\ to add the context menu entries.
Is there a way to order the enntries? Or add a separator? Or nested menu?
At the moment they are all ordered in alphabet order.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, no, there is still no good way to accomplish this seemingly simple task.

For future readers, there are two methods (one of which the OP mentions) which you can consider to add context menu items.

**Registry Method**

Unfortunately, there is no way to create "rich" menus in Internet Explorer using the [registry method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Simple 'context' filtering is available, but nothing more. To summarize this method described in the link, first add an new subkey at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\<Menu Text>
```

`<MenuText>` is the text which shows up in the context menu in Internet Explorer. Using `&` for accelerator keys does work as expected.

Set the `(Default)` value to the path of a *script* file to execute. This may be Javsascript, VB Script, etc. If you are creating a BHO, it would be wise to package it in with your DLL/EXE; access it using `res://`. For example, my system has an entry named `E&xport to Microsoft Excel` with the value:

```
res://C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office12\EXCEL.EXE/3000
```

**IDocHostUIHandler Method**

This method effectively replaces IE's entire context menu with one your BHO generates programmatically. While extremely flexible, it is [highly discouraged](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/09788ad7-a3d6-4e88-bc12-103a51ba98b0#8049ecf9-1e65-4e55-aab0-06003e734f8f). If more than one BHO attempts this, the results could be disastrous. I found a working example of this method on CodeProject's [Pop-Up Blocker tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/popupblocker2.aspx), but have not tried it myself for the reasons mentioned.

**Further reading:**

I am actively working on a project which includes many of these components. I will try to keep this post updated if I find any straightforward solutions.

- http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/17781.html
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicd/archive/2007/04/18/calling-into-your-bho-from-a-client-script.aspx
- http://1code.codeplex.com/releases/view/62253#DownloadId=215004
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/1dc29a00-12e9-45ff-a281-d72553dc79ad

Comment: + 1, Although you could not help the poster, you have certainly helped me, thanks.